# insert value in javascript depending on csv cell value

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a question on JavaScript an CSV handling:

I have a CSV File, which I parse as a string per line. For every line I have two cases on which I need to manipulate the string.

Case #1: I only need to convert the ", " with ";" to split "Name, Surname"

`888;001;52;1;Name, Surname;REPVA;SomeDocname;2017-05-01;0124721CF00C0D28D2F5C44D5547D2F0.pdf;;2017-05-01;2018-07-17;888~001~52;0124721CF00C0D28D2F5C44D5547D2F0;;`

this is already working with

```js
tmp = message.toString();
var res = tmp.replace(", ",";");
message = res;
return message;
```

Case#2: the 3rd and 5th field are empty

`888;001;;0;;REPBUCH;SomeDocname;2016-04-01;00FCC2848BA49E57490C905FB1EB4F54.pdf;;2016-04-01;2018-07-17;888~001~50;00FCC2848BA49E57490C905FB1EB4F54;;`

in this case I want to fill it with a pseudo "Name, Surname" to achieve the same string format as above in Case#1.

Comment: I could help, i need some info: what is `tmp`? where is declared? why do you do `message = res;` instead of returnig `res` directly

Comment: sorry, message is the parsed string line from the csv. tmp is a given varibale for manipulation of a message. so message.toString() is not necessary.

Comment: I will update the answer to be correct for legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a function that cover both cases:

```
function checkData(message) {
    const data = message.split(";")
    if(data[2].trim() === "") data[4] = "John, Doe"; // fix only if it's missing
    return data.join(";");
}
```

```js
var res = checkData(tmp);
var msg = res.replace(", ",";");
return msg;
```

hope it fits your needs // thanks edited your answer to match my question